# How to find files using the `find` command and add text to them?

Tags: command-line, find, output

What I am trying to do is find files using the `find` command and then add text to those files.
I tried multiple ways, but nothing works:

```
find . -type f -iname 'filename' -exec '{}' echo "hello123" > '{}'  \;
find . -type f -iname 'filename' -exec '{}' "hello123" > '{}'  \;
```

I tried the above commands but they don't work. The `find` section works properly, but the adding text section does not.

Is this close to the proper way to do it? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: First thing, remove the single quotes around `{}` and use it only after the  `echo` Command not before it … once.

Comment: Second thing, use `>>` which appends the text in a new line not `>` which replaces the whole  file’s contents.

Comment: Third thing, your first command is pretty close. Just fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Raffa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell will process the redirection `> '{}'` before running the `find` command, resulting in an output file literally named `{}`. As well, the preceding `-exec {}` will try to *execute* the found file.

You could instead do

```
find . -iname 'filename' -exec sh -c 'echo hello123 >> "$1"' find-sh {} \;
```

or (more efficiently, since it only runs one `sh` for several files found)

```
find . -iname 'filename' -exec sh -c 'for f do echo hello123 >> "$f"; done' find-sh {} +
```

Here, `find-sh` is an arbitrary string passed as the shell's zeroth positional parameter `$0`. The replacement string `{}` does not need to be quoted in most shells - see for example [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)

Alternatively, you could avoid shell redirection altogether - for example, using sed to **a**ppend your text after the last line `$` in in-place mode:

```
find . -iname 'filename' -exec sed -i '$a hello123' {} +
```

Comment: Thank you , I think i have to practice more and more

As I am beginner can you give me some advice or guidance how i can improve my  Linux skills like framing of commands etc.

Comment: @SakshamSharma we were all beginners once ;) I can recommend this [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) - be aware that some of the shell programming guides you will find on the web are unreliable though. Probably the best advice I can give is to hang out on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) since the answers there are peer reviewed by the community.

Comment: Thank you for and i will keep this in my mind :)